# FB.ui feed dialog not working with jquery mobile

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm creating a facebook app with jquery mobile and whenever I try to open a feed dialog, instead of the dialog, what I get is my app tries to load a page or something, everything vanishes except the header and the background color of the body.

I have like five buttons each one with a different ID that I get through the data-id-i-want attribute.

```
<button rel="external" data-ajax="false" data-id-i-want="<?=$buttons['id']?>" class="bt-share" data-role="button">Share</button>
```

Has you noticed all the buttons have the same class `.bt-share`

And this is my javascript to call the FB.ui feed dialog

```
$(document).on("click", ".bt-share", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                var id = $(this).data("id-i-want");

                var obj = {
                    method: 'feed',
                    link: '<?=site_url()?>?p='+ id,
                    picture: "<?=base_url('public/img/thumbnail.jpg')?>",
                    name: 'Name',
                    caption: 'https://www.facebook.com/page',
                    description: 'desc',
                    display: 'popup'
                };

                function callback(response) {
                  //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
                }

                FB.ui(obj, callback);
            });
```

There's a conflict somewhere between the FB.ui and jquery mobile, as I think that jquery mobile is trying to load something

Comment: Were you able to find any fix...??

Comment: instead of using the dialog I have redirected the user to the Dialog URL. Since jquery mobile use hashtags and so does the fb.ui dialog they create a conflict between them, so that was the only solution I could found